# Transfer money between accounts in solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am writing a contract where I want to transfer money (present in the contract owners account and not the contract) to an account address passed to a function in the contract.

for some reason this code won't work

```
function payBill(uint value, address account) payable public {
    account.transfer(value);
    transactionCount += 1;
    transactionAmount += value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be related to any frontend code, not only this.
You've got two options.

1. get that other user address from the contract and then run a direct transaction between two accounts (example here https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-eth.html#id80)
2. send a value (see here https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-eth-contract.html#id33) when you are calling the payBill method. If you don't do it, the default value is zero, and you don't see any transfer.

Also, please consider having a look at this https://diligence.consensys.net/blog/2019/09/stop-using-soliditys-transfer-now/

EDIT:

what you are trying to do here, is also not doable. This requires the contract to have the number of funds that you want to transfer. That is because, with the payable method, you are sending funds to the contract, but the funds will only be in the contract, once the transaction is accepted. On the other hand, you are trying to send that number of funds to another user, without having them on the contract. That is why you never see any balance.